# How to list global dataproc clusters in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to get a list of all my global dataproc clusters, but can't seem to find a way to do so.  The clusters.list API only returns non-global clusters at the `v1beta2/projects/{projectId}/regions/{region}/clusters` endpoint.  Hitting this with the `GLOBAL` region throws an error, saying it's not a valid region.  I can't seem to find a global clusters endpoint.

I've tried doing something like `client.discovered.projects.global.clusters`, but I get an exception telling me global isn't a method.  The [docs on URIs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses#creating_resource_uris) seem to indicate this is the way one should list global resources.

How can I get a list of all my global dataproc clusters?

Comment: Please use lower case "global"

Comment: Wow, serious facepalm moment.  Yup, it was indeed a casing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766460/how-to-list-global-dataproc-clusters-in-gcp#comment94385544_53766460) you need to use lower-case  `global` as a region in URL:

```
v1beta2/projects/{projectId}/regions/global/clusters
```